# Can someone help me in convert this MySql query to sequelize?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am new to sequelize. I am not sure how to convert this MySql query so that I can use it in my node.js file.

MySql query:

```
SELECT Rtrim(Ltrim(childstatus)),TIMESTAMPDIFF(d,dob,now(3)) 
INTO @childstatus, @Ageday 
FROM childdetails where registno=@registno
```

I have sequelize model for childdetails. I am not sure how to structure this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Sequelize.fn` to call these two functions indicating them in `attributes` option like this:

```js
const details = await ChildDetials.findAll({
  attributes: [
  [Sequelize.fn('RTrim', Sequelize.fn('LTrim', Sequelize.col('childstatus'))), 'childsttaus'],
  [Sequelize.fn('TIMESTAMPDIFF', Sequelize.literal('d'), Sequelize.col('dob'), Sequelize.fn('now', 3)), 'Ageday']
  ],
  where: {
    registno: registno
  }
})
```